# Not Able To Open APK file in my android device?

Tags: java, android

I'm not able to install my app on any other android device and the irony is that, the app is working fine in AVD and on my device. I don't know why but everytime I install, it says "Installation Failed" or "App not Installed" !
Thanks in advance for answering the question.

Below is my `build.gradle` file:-

```
android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sangeetplayer"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to share your manifest as well and also any of the stack trace/logs as that could give more info.

One of the common reasons might be that the OS versions might miss match ( your device vs AVD) or a corrupted manifest file

Comment: I encounter this message with my apk in 2 cases:
1. the Android version on the device you install on is less than MinSdk that you provided in your project. You have MinSdk = 21, which corresponds to Android 5.0 .
2. You already have installed a version which is a signed one and you want to install a non-signed version. Or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

You must be installing the **debug** build of your app on other devices. For installing your app on other devices, you've to build a **release** build of your app. You would need a `key store` to sign your apk.

Follow below steps to generate a signed apk

- In the menu bar, click **Build** > **Generate Signed Bundle/APK**.
- In the Generate Signed Bundle or APK dialog, select APK and click Next.
- Below the field for Key store path, click Create new.
- On the New Key Store window, provide the required information for your Keystore and key
- Once you complete the form, click OK.
- Select the build type, click ok

Your release build apk would be in project folder -> release